# Python parse XML from online web service

Tags: python, xml

I have been trying to use python to parse an XML that I get from a webserver. The link to the XML is http://gagnaveita.vegagerdin.is/api/faerd2014_1. It does not matter which library I use I always end up with really weird results, it doesn't parse and the file. Also whenever I try to save the file it doesn't display like a XML at all. Any idea of how to parse a flie like that?

Comment: try to validate the xml first

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow!  We really can't help you unless you show us the code you're using, and demonstrate clearly both the results you are seeing and how they differ from the results you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run this link in browser it shows me XML data.

But when I try to read this in script I get JSON file.

The same when I use `wget` command (on Linux) - I get JSON file.

Maybe you have the same situation.

-

Or maybe browser gets JSON data but it use own method to show it and I get XML on screen :)

---

**EDIT:** I found answer - server check `accept` header. If there is `xml` then it sends XML file.

Try with and without `headers`

```
import requests

headers = {
   'Accept': 'application/xml',
}

r = requests.get('http://gagnaveita.vegagerdin.is/api/faerd2014_1', headers=headers)

print(r.content)
#print(r.json())
```

Comment: I have to say - this page behaves strange - I don't know why browser shows it as XML. I tried change `user-agent` header in script but this changes  nothing.

Comment: I found answer - result depends on `"accept"` header - if there is `xml` then server XML